# Promises inside for loops

Tags: promise, protractor

I'm struggling with this:

- Click a button to get a set of data
- Check the number of rows returned is what I'm expecting
- I need to run this 10 times, each time, I'm expecting a different number of rows

The code snippet below doesn't work because 'i' isn't what I'm expecting.  How can I make this work?

```
for (var i = 0; i < subElements.length; ++i) {
    element(by.id('get-data')).click();

    // Check users returned
    element.all(by.id('users')).map(function (elm) {
        return elm;
    }).then(function (users) {
        expect(users.length).toBe(expectedRecords[i]);
        // Some more checks to be added later
    });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: What is `subElements`? Could you show the relevant HTML code? I think this can be solved differently in a protractor-style :)

Comment: I solved this by creating a helper function.  In the main function, I run thru the for loop, calling the helper function.  The helper function does the checks.  Don't this is a clean way of doing it so I didn't post, but it's working for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
for (var i = 0; i < subElements.length; ++i) {
    element(by.id('get-data')).click();

    var count = element.all(by.id('users')).count();
    expect(count).toBe(expectedRecords[i]);
}
```

As long as you aren't accessing `i` in a `then`, it will be what you want, otherwise `i` will the the last value in your loop and you'll need closure.

EDIT: see [Using protractor with loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910331/using-protractor-with-loops/27910350)

Answer (score 0):

Using bluebird

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

it('my test', function(done){
  var promises = subElements.map(function(subElm, i){
    return element(by.id('get-data')).click()
      .then(function(){
        // Check users returned
        return element.all(by.id('users')).map(function (elm) {
          return elm;
        })
      })
      .then(function(users) {
        expect(users.length).toBe(expectedRecords[i]);
      });
  });

  Promise.all(promises).nodeify(done);
})
```